# What is missing from this OIDC JWT?

Tags: firebase, jwt, openid-connect

I have a React app that is using Firebase to authenticate users. Firebase works fine for Google SSO users, but I am trying to add a custom OIDC Provider (a Laravel app I control) and Firebase returns the error 'Unable to parse the ID Token'. Based on evidence I'll provide below, I think that maybe I'm missing some data in the token that Firebase needs, but it's unclear what it wants or thinks is missing.

I used [OpenID Connect Playground](https://openidconnect.net/) to debug my flow so far and  I'm able to successfully go through steps one and two steps, but on step three when I click the 'verify' button it gives a 400 error and reports 'There was an error verifying your token. Try again.'. The steps are as follows.

1. Redirect to OpenID Connect Server
2. Exchange Code from Token
3. Verify User Token

However, the JWT appears to be at least well-formed, as I can view it on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/?_gl=1*1m45h7x*_ga*MjE0MDcyMDEwOS4xNzA4NDQ2NjM5*_ga_QKMSDV5369*MTcwOTI0MjE0MS45LjEuMTcwOTI0MzMyNC41Ny4wLjA.#debugger?&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6bnVsbCwic3ViIjoxfQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5teS5mdXNlc3R1ZGlvLm5ldCIsInN1YiI6IjEiLCJhdWQiOiI5YjcwMTRhZC1hY2E2LTQ2NmYtYmUzYy1iYWI5MTQwZDM2OTciLCJleHAiOjE3MDkxNTMyNDYuMDgwNzE0LCJpYXQiOjE3MDkxNTI2NDYuMDgwNzE0LCJqdGkiOiJjMGUzYWFiY2Y3MDY0ZDc5NWY2N2ZjMDVkNGM2ZDdiMjI4NGJiNmVlNWQyYmYwMjEzZTljN2RlZmExZjg3ZTY1M2UwM2E5OGZlNmZhMzQ0OCIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTcwOTE1MjYzOCwibm9uY2UiOm51bGx9.erDFD1y9luAXEJjilj9aaRu5FUdlvAelPrprjbYHxZT6HdVRZLziyr6Moz7BYMMJ9tzdua4upuGgac2s6nzV-jfqB_eln9putBjaTxSEU8CeJIID4vnKAiF0bJKsfCKq0APbaKYz0SqDkFJysCBt_tdI_GcC9h0Y0b07WmGu6KmuOzv0RCNj4BUXaTiOY73SCvm5cE_RyKu4h9nSvd_qzn0Jhg1zEA0_WUf8VtnlhOhdzqEhR3MNsjSgtm-ki6D7_1zl48GupFC75LuIvBBaNLqYktxMOlKMHGAJVsw9cCON0y5u-TNvI8DGtYmt0zvSd85294myJjnkZg8cr6OBDsLBKgWH3eg0H94hyGduPi0pWXMGqh2cOwIxHE_qe2a2bFezjsW6UqDipVlIMJEIAr5Jdp2Jv-D0YVmV5VF6QpJwCYKdE3N1GaTbqzTRPiMbUC4MQ5lBst-PSiM6FO0J92zLh1FS_6Tn_beO4K8-7UmVb1-QH6LutNELhYxLWPxrJivFGsXXy1ZLTGdJOxNBHLzim8K_JtRx3x7V548RsAl_H22arzu2oMl284k9noWs2C50CZDsYu8q6wPAZNVq_ZhVGlbjN6rfzgoPWOMY2zGOEDE15kiQ3Yv5S-VSjmtCfgU-uz0p6dAt653wMS0uS1sfhLcyA789WKT3sa_DtdE) and the output is

### Header: Algorithm & Token Type

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": null,
  "sub": 1
}
```

### Payload: Data

```json
{
  "iss": "https://dev.my.fusestudio.net",
  "sub": "1",
  "aud": "9b7014ad-aca6-466f-be3c-bab9140d3697",
  "exp": 1709153246.080714,
  "iat": 1709152646.080714,
  "jti": "c0e3aabcf7064d795f67fc05d4c6d7b2284bb6ee5d2bf0213e9c7defa1f87e653e03a98fe6fa3448",
  "auth_time": 1709152638,
  "nonce": null
}
```

There is a "Verify Signature" area on the jwt.io webpage, and when I paste in my private key, it returns "Signature Verified".

Based on this I think there is a field missing in the JWT Payload or Header, but it's not clear to me what exactly is missing.

Comment: My guess is that since the JWT header has a null kid, the server doesn't know which key to validate it against.
Be sure to populate the header's kid with the kid of the key you use to sign the JWT

Comment: *There is a "Verify Signature" area on the jwt.io webpage, and when I paste in my private key, it returns "Signature Verified".* - you should paste the **public key** to verify the signature, not the private key.

Comment: @jps - the "Verify Signature" box on jwt.io clearly states that it wants "Private Key in PKCS #8, PKCS #1, or JWK string format. The key never leaves your browser."

Comment: The jwt.io debugger works in both directions and if you provide the private key it can happen that the signature will be recalculated with that key and then it is automatically verified. If you only provide the public key you can really see if the token can be verified with that key. The private key is not necessary for verification.

Comment: Interesting. Pasting the public key in the field returns "Invalid Signature".

Comment: @pochopsp's hint was helpful. The key id (kid) needs to be a string, and there needs to be a key with a matching kid in the `.well-known/jwks.json` file. Once I got those to match, The OpenID Connect Playground now declares "The token is valid!". However, Google's Firebase still returns the error 'Unable to parse the ID Token'.

Comment: @selfsimilar glad for being of help. The error "unable to parse the ID token" looks almost like Firebase has problem to deserialize the ID Token. Are you sure it doesn't expect something encrypted? From what I got, you are only signing it. The ID Token is often needed to be encrypted since it usually contains sensitive information